# Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 133 - CocoaPods error macOS Sierra

Tags: ios, macos, cocoapods, xcode8, macos-sierra

I have iOS project and have add CocoaPos. It was working fine with Mac OSX EL Capitan. Just upgraded my OS to macOS Sierra and the project stopped working.

When I building the project getting compile error in all CocoaPods target.

Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 133

I have Xcode 8.0.

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Comment: it's an underlying issue with code signing on Sierra - see this thread:https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/64784, and this (closed) cocoa pods issue: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5995

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure this will help without further info but I had a similar issue.  I had to run the following update then my issue was fixed:

```
sudo gem update gh_inspector
```

Hope it helps.